# How I can make Tomcat 7 to respond with static file slow?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

For the testing purposes I need to make Tomcat to respond with late http responses. It is quite clear how to do it for the servlet responses. But it is not clear if I want Tomcat to answer, say with 10000 ms delay for each static file request. How it can be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this write - you want to introduce a 10000 ms delay for any incoming request where you are serving a static resource.

The easy way to do this is via a servlet filter mapped to the default servlet.

For brevity ...

```
doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)  {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Then map the filter to the default servlet:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>delayFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```